# How can display a prompt message for several seconds in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript, I know I can use MsgBox(prompt[, buttons][, title][, helpfile, context]) to display a message box.

But I hope to display a prompt message for several seconds, then the prompt message will disappear automatically, just like the android code ablow

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Will Do..." ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method for that.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Will do ...", 5, "Title", vbOKOnly
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a VBScript message box, two more factors needed:
- Icon
- Title

So if 16 = X icon, 32 = ? Icon, 48 = ! Icon, and 64 = i Icon,

```
X=MsgBox("Will do...",ICON,"TITLE")
```

For the title, probably do your program name.
As for the icon, 64 is probably good.

```
X=MsgBox("Will do...",64,"Program Name")
```